# C++ Parse ASCII file to struct

Tags: c++, struct

I have an ascii file where each line is an entry, here is an example:

```
8331          CP-65 3951 5.62a-0.003
8332          BD-06 5827 6.17b+0.049
8333   Omi IndCP-70 2873 5.53c-0.031
8334 10Nu  CepBD+60 2288 4.29d-0.003
8335 81Pi 2CygBD+48 3504 4.23e+0.004
```

The format of the file is as follows:

```
---------------------------------
   Bytes Format  Units   Label   
---------------------------------
   1-  4  I4     ---     HR       
   5- 14  A10    ---     Name   
  15- 25  A11    ---     DM      
  26-29 F5.2   mag     Vmag  
     30  A1     ---   n_Vmag
  31-36  F6.3 arcsec/yr pmRA
```

I have a corresponding struct which I want to populate (each line of the file will be an instance of the struct):

```
struct star{
    int id; // 4 bytes ascii representation
    string name; // 10 bytes ascii representation
    string dm; // 11 bytes ascii representation
    float Vmag; // F5.2 - 5 bytes ascii representation, 2 bytes after the floating point (e.g:  2.91 , space at the begining)
    char n_Vmag; // 1 byte ascii representation
    float pmRA; // F6.3 - 6 bytes ascii representation, 3 bytes after the floating point (e.g: +0.006)
};
```

I came up with the following code, but does not work, would appreciate some guidance towards an elegant solution:

```
    std::string line;
    //while (std::getline(infile, line))
    for (;;)
    {
        star s;
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        char id[4];
        char name[10];
        char dm[11];

        //if (!infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s.id), 4) ||
        if (!infile.read(id, 4) ||
            !infile.read(name, 14) ||
            !infile.read(dm, 25))
        {
            // error or end of file
        }
```

Comment: What does, "does not work" mean?  Please be specific!

Comment: Likewise with "guidance".  Stackoverflow is a Q/A website, not a chat forum.

Comment: Please, Please, search StackOverflow for "c++ read file struct".  Always, search before posting.  One of these examples has got to help you.

Comment: In "line by line" cases where the format is fixed width, I would read the line (e.g. with `std::getline`), then separate it from that string.